# Writing to csv using pandas data frame after scraping data

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I successfully scraped this website and the data is scraped correctly. The only problem is exporting to csv. I used pandas to export data and it got jumbled up. Below is my code:

```
while next_page is not None:

    results_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", '
                                                    '"label-primary", " " ))]')

    results = [x.text for x in results_element]

    print(results)

    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    ASIN_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "asin-column", '
        '" " ))]//a')

    ASIN = [x.text for x in ASIN_element]
    print(ASIN)

    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    Title_element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.asin-column+ td')

    Title = [x.text for x in Title_element]
    print(Title)

    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    Date_element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        '.format-date'), 10

    Date = [x for x in Date_element]
    print(Date)

    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(results, ASIN, Title, Date)), columns=['results', 'ASIN', 'Product_Title', 'Date'])

    beach_balls_data = df.to_csv(f, index=False)

    if next_page is not None:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.next a').click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    elif next_page is None:
        iterate = False
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    time.sleep(5)
```

I just need to export the data properly without overwriting anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please post your actual & expected output

Comment: it makes headers again every time  the loop iterates, that's the main problem. If u may help, that would  be great

Comment: how about moving     beach_balls_data = df.to_csv(f, index=False) outside the while loop

Comment: then it will save data after every iteration and a blank csv will be created.

Comment: the basic idea is to use dataframe to collect the data. Once data collection is complete, then write it to csv once.This should avoid any duplicate column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Below (not using pandas or any other library)

```
# assuming the scraping output is the 4 lists below

results = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3']
asin_lst = ['asin1', 'asin2', 'asin3']
title_lst = ['t1', 't2', 't3']
date_lst = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3']

with open('out.csv','w') as f:
    f.write('result,asin,title,date\n')
    for entry in list(zip(results,asin_lst,title_lst,date_lst)):
        f.write(','.join(list(entry)) + '\n')
```

output ('out.csv')

```
result,asin,title,date
r1,asin1,t1,d1
r2,asin2,t2,d2
r3,asin3,t3,d3
```